# SQL Set Max Affected Rows for Session

Tags: sql, sql-server

I work with a group of people in a DEV environment and sometimes we get a little anxious on the F5. I would say on a monthly basis someone updates every record in a table instead of just 1 or 2 because they miss the were clause or were doing something like

```
Begin Transaction

update table1 
set column1 = '50'

select * from table1
where column2= 'abc'
and column3 = '123'

 If @@ROWCOUNT != 1
    Begin
        Rollback
        Print 'Failed ' + @Ticket
    End
 else
    Begin
        commit
        Print 'Success ' + @Ticket
    End
```

In this case they meant to comment or delete the select line. My question is, can you set something to auto rollback if more than X number of rows are affected? I can never see them updating more than 400 or so. I have told them to you Begin Transaction and @@RowCount to verify but since it is 2 statements and the 2nd has the right number it doesn't help.

Comment: The only way of doing this would be to add a trigger to every table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt SQL Server out of the box provides a solution for you.  if this is a big issue, then deploy SQL Server database backup, with regularly scheduled log backups, so you can restore to a given point in time.  Or, restrict their access so they are updating/inserting/deleting/querying from procs only (this probably won't scale, but it's an option).  Or tell them to use TOP in all their queries.

In the meantime, ensure your devs never, ever, troubleshoot on a prod system.

Comment: I suspected that I was hoping for some type of nested Transaction, and using perhaps a variable to sum all the @@ROWCOUNTS

Comment: Educate them on using TOP while you are at it.  But if they keep forgetting to add a WHERE clause, it probably won't help either.

Comment: thanks, I will mark this as the answer if no one comes up with anything by EOD

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the developers performing these `update` queries need to be more rigorous.  Every update-- even in development-- should be written with a `begin tran` and `rollback` until they are sure that the query updates the correct rows.

For example, I always use the following template:

```
-- review the data to be updated
select * from MyTable where MyColumn = 'A'

begin tran

update MyTable
set MyColumn = 'B'
where MyColumn = 'A'

-- be sure the query updated the expected number of rows
select @@rowcount 

-- re-review the original data to make sure those rows were changed
select * from MyTable where MyColumn = 'A'

-- reverse the changes; change this to a commit *only* when the above is proven to be correct
rollback
```

**-- EDIT --**

Adapting this to your example, you could capture the @@ROWCOUNT in a variable and refer to it later.  For example:

```
declare @RowsUpdated int = 0

Begin Transaction

update table1 
set column1 = '50'

-- capture the @@ROWCOUNT for use later
select @RowsUpdated = @@ROWCOUNT

-- you could add row counts from multiple update statements together:
-- select @RowsUpdated = @RowsUpdated + @@ROWCOUNT

select * from table1
where column2= 'abc'
and column3 = '123'

If @RowsUpdated != 1
Begin
    Rollback
    Print 'Failed ' + @Ticket
End
else
Begin
    commit
    Print 'Success ' + @Ticket
End
```

Comment: I agree with you but in my example this wouldn't help, because the Update would take place, then the select statement, which would select the correct number of rows since it has the where clause and so it commits (updated for example)

Comment: You could capture the `@@ROWCOUNT` after the `UPDATE` and refer to it later.  However, no, there is no way to do this automatically as far as SQL server is concerned.  If it's always the same table, you could add a trigger that does a `rollback` if more than 1 row is being updated at once.  This seems like a lot of work if you want to do this on any table.